# How do I use Laplace's equation to solve this differential equation?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

Suppose we have Laplace's equation for some $u(x,y)$ as:

$$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2} = 0$$

for $x \geq 0$, and $0 \leq y \leq a$, and that $u(x,y) \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$. We have the boundary conditions:

$$u(x,0) = u(x, a) = 0$$ 
$$u(0, y) = \sin (\pi y/a) + 2 \sin (2\pi y /a )$$

I want to solve this equation using separation of variables.

What I've done:

1. I let $u(x,y) = X(x)Y(y)$ to transform the equation into

$$ Y\frac{d^2 X}{dx^2} + X\frac{d^2 Y}{dy^2} = 0$$

2. Then I solve for the following ODE:

$$ \frac{d^2 X}{dx^2} - \lambda X = 0$$
$$ \frac{d^2 Y}{dy^2} + \lambda Y = 0$$

where we have

$$ \frac{1}{X} \frac{d^2 X}{dx^2} = - \frac{1}{Y} \frac{d^2 Y}{dy^2} = \lambda$$

However note that in this step I have no clue where the $\lambda$ eigenvalue comes from as it is something I adopted from a similar question.

3. Till now I have no idea how to apply the boundary conditions or to check if $\lambda$ should be positive or negative in order to express $X$ or $Y$ as exponential and sinusodial functions respectively.

How should I proceed?

Comment: 'However, note that in this step I have no clue where the $\lambda$ eigenvalue comes from'. It comes from the fact that if a function of the variable $x$ is equal to a function of the variable $y$ for all $x, y$ in the domain of the PDE, then they must equal a constant, which we will call $\lambda$. It turns out that $\lambda$ ends up being an eigenvalue of your ODEs. To proceed, you need to solve $Y'' = -\lambda Y$, subject to the boundary conditions $Y(0) = Y(a) = 0$, for the cases $\lambda < 0, \lambda = 0, \lambda > 0$. You should find only $\lambda > 0$ yields non-trivial solutions.

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification, I was only told to memorise this but not understand the intuition behind the concept unfortunately, so this really helps!

Comment: No worries. Also, I forgot to mention something. The reason why the boundary conditions are $Y(0) = Y(a) = 0$ comes from the PDE boundary conditions and your ansatz that $u(x,y) = X(x)Y(y)$. For example, you have that $u(x,0) = 0 = X(x)Y(0)$. This implies that either $X(x) = 0$ or $Y(0) = 0$. If $X(x) = 0$, the solution would be given by $u(x,y) = 0 \cdot Y(y) = 0$ which is trivial and hence we discard it. So it must be that $Y(0) = 0$. You can apply similar reasoning for the other BC.

Comment: Remember that your example must a priori exhibit $X''=\lambda \implies Y'' = -\lambda$

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts thanks for noting the error, I have since corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an equation $f(x)=g(y,z,\cdots)$, and there is no $x$ dependence on the right, then fixing $y,z,\cdots$ results in the right side being constant in $x$, which means the left side must be constant in $x$. So there is a constant $\lambda$ such that $f(x)=\lambda$, $\lambda=g(y,z,\cdots)$. The permissible constants $\lambda$ are then determined by the equation $f(x)=\lambda$ and endpoint conditions in $x$. Once the possible values of $\lambda$ are known, then must solve $\lambda=g(y,z,\cdots)$ for all such possible $\lambda$. Now you separate again, and find a new parameter $\mu$. Etc.